# How are those time positions values encoded in bytes?

Tags: file-format

I am reversing a file with no documentation.

I identified chunks of data (8 bytes); on the left is what is expected (hours, minutes, seconds, 1/60 of second) and on the right, the raw bytes.

```
// 00:00:00:00 0000000000000000
// 00:15:43:59 412BA7EAD70A3D71
// 01:11:48:00 414F8D834C49BA5E
// 02:02:59:20 415B06219B020C4A
// 02:14:36:27 415D93ADB570A3D7
// 02:30:29:59 416088CF8A45A1CB
```

I could not find how the time positions were encoded.

I tried (c#) `new TimeSpan(BitConverter.ToInt64(x))` where x is the whole 64 bits, with x normal and reversed; and `BitConverter.ToInt16(x)` where x is a 16 bits.

The original software is written in c++ I believe.

Any clue ?

Comment: Read these 8-byte chunks as "double" floating-point numbers.

Comment: @ESkri Thanks, that's almost it, if the double is considered as milliseconds. Any idea about the difference with the reference ? eg., 00:15:06.2294200 (calculated) v 00:15:43:59 (reference)